# Retrieving Native Videos via LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

We are using LinkedIn API to retrieve the updates that were posted on the company page.
All the available updates are returned by the API beside Native Videos.
Is there a way to pull Native Videos via the API?

Please refer me to any documentation / Instructions.

Comment: Hi Limor, were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: yes, it is available from V2 API (as shares)

Comment: can you please share your code, or tell me which API you used? I tried https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/shares?oauth2_access_token={token} and https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:{id}&oauth2_access_token={token}. Both fail :_(